# Laravel Route [createnewpassword] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, variables, redirect, routes

I have created a password forget system for users to create new passwords. First of all, I let users enter their email addresses in a form at passwordforget.blade.php. Then I verify the email to see the email address in the database. If the email address is not in the database, the user is redirected back to the same route/page with an error message: "Email address not found".

But if the email address is confirmed to be in the database, the user is redirected to createnewpassword.blade.php to create a new password. But Laravel tells me that the Route [createnewpassword] is not defined.

```
public function pwdforget(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
    if (!$user) {
        return back()->with('fail', 'We could not recognize your email address');
    } else {
        $email = $user->email;

        return Redirect::route('createnewpassword')->with(['email' => $email]);
    }
}
```

I tried to Redirect to a new Route with Data. I want to be able to successfully to a createnewpassword.blade.php and display the database in the blade template.

Comment: share your route from `web.php`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return view('createnewpassword', ['email' => $email])` if you're referring to a blade template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

```
return redirect()->route('createnewpassword', ['email' => $email]);
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/createnewpassword', [YourController::class, 'createnewpassword'])->name('createnewpassword');
```

Make sure to run the following command to refresh the routes.

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: It worked in the way: